# variable, passed together with event, does not change

Tags: javascript

When I call editWorkout function for the first time, the variable 'workout' gets passed in the editWorkout2 function, but then, during the second time, when the same thing happens, but in this case 'workout' has new value, this value for some reason won't change in editWorkout2 function. How can I fix that?

```
function editWorkout(e, workout) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    console.log(workout);
    editWorkout2(e, workout);
  }.bind(this)
);
```

}

Comment: You are going to be binding multiple events to the same button. `addEventListener` does not replace events so you are going to have 2 click events added if you call editWorkout two times.

Comment: Real solution is hard to tell with the information provided. The real solution would not involve adding event listeners inside other event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

on each call of your `editWorkout` function, you're adding a new event listener to your "saveBtn" element with the same event type.

I recommend you read the usage notes of [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#syntax).

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was as follows: because during the second call and all of the consecutive calls of the function **editWorkout** the event listener was going on top of the previous one, for some reason variable **workout** was not changing in that eventListener as a parameter. So I removed event listener in the **editWorkout2** function, and everything started working fine